# The list that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. An enumerator can only be used if the list is not changed

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I created the code below wich never gave me any error:

```
foreach (var item in clb_frente_campos.CheckedItems)
{
    if (item == "numero_carteira")
    {            
        clb_frente_impressao.Items.Add(item);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!clb_frente_impressao.Items.Contains(item))
        {
            clb_frente_impressao.Items.Add(item);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is a button to pass the `checked` value from one `CheckedListBox` to another.
Notice that, while the item `numero_carteira` is `checked` it will be added over and over to my other `CheckedListBox`. Because the item `numero_carteira` is the only item that can be added more than once. But I wanted him to be added **ONLY** when it was `selected`, that's why I made this new code:

```
foreach (var item in clb_frente_campos.CheckedItems)
{
    if (item == "numero_carteira")
    {
        if (clb_frente_campos.SelectedItem.ToString() == "numero_carteira")
        {
            clb_frente_impressao.Items.Add(item);
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!clb_frente_impressao.Items.Contains(item))
        {
            clb_frente_impressao.Items.Add(item);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And this new code is what are giving me that `error` that are in the title.
**Also and the most strange thing i ever seen**. When I use `breakpoints` and debug it step by step... It **works** How?Why?

Comment: Please, if you are going to downvote it, at least have the courage to post here the reason. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it works when you use the debugger, you almost certainly have a threading issue. It's difficult to debug without seeing the rest of your code, but my gut feeling is to look for other places you might loop on `clb_frente_impressao.Items`.

Comment: This is my feeling as well, but this seems like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: But that is my whole code... All of that are inside a `ImageButton_Click` Event..

Comment: @Ghaleon You don't use `clb_frente_impressao` anywhere? Then, what's the point of having it?

Comment: @MikeCaron It just hold the items I've selected FROM `clb_frente_campos`. You know ? Initially, `clb_frente_campos` are totally empty, then I start selecting the items FROM ´clb_frente_campos` and adding these items to the `clb_frente_impressão`. And the error happens on the `ForEach` .